# Cypress: How to handle closing of window confirm triggered from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

I need help on how to close a confirmation window which was triggered from an iframe. I am trying the code below, but this still can't close the confirm window.

```
 cy.get('iframe[id="ParentMainContent_Frame"]').then(($iframe) => {
        const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
        const $win = $iframe[0].contentWindow

        cy.stub($win,'confirm').as('windowConfirm')
        cy.wrap($body)
        .find('#ParentMainContent_MainContentMaster_ctl00_PlaceOrderButton').click().should(function () {
            expect(this.windowConfirm).to.be.calledWith('Thank you for your Order!')
        })
    })
```

[image: DOM]

The button triggering this window is shown above:

Hoping someone could take a look and help.

Comment: iFrame handling is tricky, I recommend using [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe). But maybe try `cy.spy()` instead of `cy.stub()` since spy allows the original behavior but stub blocks the original behavior.

Comment: Hi @eric99, I tried cy.spy but i'm still unable to click the conf window. Do you have a working example on how to do this?

Comment: The easiest way to handle iframes is with [Cypress iframe](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe/-/tree/master). What might be missing in your code is waiting for the iframe to load, e.g `Cypress.$(contentWindow).on('load', resolve)` is how it's done in this library.

Answer (score 0):

Using [cypress-iframe](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe) gives you more checks that the iframe loading has finished before you start testing it's contents.

The downside is this library's methods yield `body` but not the iframe window, though I think you can use `body.ownerDocument.window` to get it.

```js
cy.enter('iframe[id="ParentMainContent_Frame"]').then(getBody => {

  const body = getBody();
  const win = body.ownerDocument.window;

  cy.spy(win,'confirm').as('windowConfirm');   // spy not stub

  body.find('#ParentMainContent_MainContentMaster_ctl00_PlaceOrderButton')
    .click()
    .should(function () {
      expect(this.windowConfirm).to.be.calledWith('Thank you for your Order!')
    })
  }) 
})
```

Comment: Hi @eric99, I tried this one but I'm getting an error about window being 'undefined':